# How to add php code directly into article using Jumi plugin

Tags: php, javascript, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, jumi

Hi every one I have installed **Jumi plugin version 2.0 in joomla 1.5** and tried to write php code in the article. I'm able to use the code if I store the php source in an external file and call it within the content like **{jumi [../../filename.php]}**. But I'm not able to write the same code directly into the content using JCE editor. I'm getting an error like 'Jumi is working but the source needts to come under square brackets'. The problem is that I need to use a php variable output for a div tag and js also.  I have no clue of how to overcome this.

Comment: Is anyone there to answer me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never had much luck with JUMI for that and other reasons, so switched to [DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/4470) and kept the PHP right in the article itself.

Comment: cool, thankyou so much for introducing me to this easy plugin. This is what I needed. I wonder why peple talk more about Jumi and other while there is a flexible plugin like DirectPhp is available.

Comment: Anyone know why DirectPHP doesn't output something like `$this->countModules("XX")`? It creates an error on the page.

//edit:
You can write the statement like this rather: <http://www.corephp.com/blog/how-to-use-countmodules-in-any-joomla-file/#.UUjcrKUWr8s>